# i want to call a web url of a .php file when a button is clicked

Tags: android

I am updating my current location to the database I have created the database and a php file and hosted in web. I have made an android app to get current latitude and longitude and now I want to update it in database using this link this link will contain my lat&lon value, I just want to call this link in background when button is clicked.

[Here](https://androidproject2914.000webhostapp.com/stest.php?Lat=12.25&Lon=121) is the link to be called.

Comment: so what problems do you have trying to achieve that ?

Comment: Simply use the volley or retrofit library to make the request to the php file.